# C# Visual Studio Android App Showing a wrong not working Keypad on Entry text

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I'm struggling to get the correct keyboard to show and be able to insert numbers and the decimal symbol but I'm faced with a strange situation.

This is what i got with Android Studio using Java code:

[image]

Here the xml code to show this keypad:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
```

So in this case everything works fine, i can digit numbers and dot to separate decimals.

Using Visual Studio with Net Xamarin and Syncfusion the keypad change like this:

[image]

The Keypad Show the negative sign and the dot.
I can insert in the negative sign doing double tap as the first char but not the dot.
The dot is never get showed on the textbox.

here is the xml code to call the numeric keypad:

```
    <control:BorderlessEntry
    x:Name="StretchRatioLenEntry"
    Placeholder="(Es. 3,3)"
    Keyboard= "Numeric"

    Style="{StaticResource BorderlessEntryStyle}"
    Text="{Binding StretchRatioLen.Value}" PlaceholderColor="#7B7B7B">

    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviour:NumberEntryBehavior IsValid="{Binding StretchRatioLen.IsValid}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</control:BorderlessEntry>
```

So do you have any suggestion?

Thanks for your help.

here a picture from the emulator:

[image]

as you can see, this is what i want but on the real device the keypad change.

Comment: doesn't Spanish use a comma as the decimal separator?

Comment: Yes! Spanish use the comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: then what do you need the "." for?  Regardless, this sounds like a bug you should probably file with SF support

Comment: dosen't matter the dot or the comma is the keypad the problem. I'm going to add a picture from the emulator. in the emulator work fine, but when you install it in phones or tablet appear the other keypad.